In my main report, how do I reference to a field that lives in a subreport?
I'm trying to print a message on my main report based on an existing value that comes from a subreport.
I tried adding the field to my main report with the same name, however it says that the field cannot be found.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
